# how the output is calculated?

Tags: c

I'm confused in this program how the value of x=320 ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int a=5;
int main(){
    int x;
    x=~a+a&a+a<<a;
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/UBgkwdYl

hoping for quick and positive response..

Comment: Whoever written this code should retire, no offence. No wonder you couldn't read/understand it - LOOK AT THAT! (I assume this is a code sample, right?!)

Comment: Thank You for your Generosity..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is evaluated like this:

```
x = ((~a) + a) & ((a + a) << a);
```

You should review the C operator precedence tables.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, that will only give you 320 if your implementation uses two's complement encoding for integers. The reason why is because it's interpreted as:

```
  (((~a) + a) & ((a + a) << a))
=      -1     &     (10   << 5)
=           10 << 5
=             320
```

The -1 in two's complement is all 1-bits so when you `and` that with anything, you get the same value.

However, with one's complement, `~a + a` will give you zero so that the final result is zero.

The ISO C standard allows two's complement, one's complement and sign/magnitude encoding for signed integers and this is one reason why such code is inherently bad.

Comment: Change `int` to `unsigned` and it's well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Bits Operators](http://docs.hp.com/en/B3901-90013/ch05s04.html) OR this [Bits Operators](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know)

Answer (score -1):

The code makes use of the following operators (listed in the order shown in the equation):

- ~
- +
- &
- <<

Given the [operator precedence table for the C languages](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), the operators will be evaluated in the following order:

- ~
- +
- <<
- &

Given this, we have the following steps:

1. ~5. The bitwise negation of 5 (which, in binary, is 0000101) is 250 (which, in binary, is 11111010).
2. ~5 + 5 is 250 + 5, or 255.
3. 5 + 5 is 10.
4. 10 << 5 is the value of 10 (which, in binary, is 00001010) left shifted five bits, which is 320 (which, in binary, is 101000000).
5. 255 (which, in binary, is 11111111) joined in a Boolean AND operation with 320 (which, in binary, is 101000000) gives a value of 320 (which, in binary, is 101000000).

This gives the final value of 320.

Comment: ~5 is not 250. Even if `a` were not already an `int`, default promotions would promote it up to `int`. In fact, regardless of which signed integer form an implementation uses, `~positive` must always be negative.

Comment: Also your last step is wrong and should have clued you in to an earlier step being wrong. `255&320` is not 320.